# Difference between two named Special Purpose Registers - MBR and IR

Tags: cpu-registers

What is the difference between Memory Buffer Register(MBR) and Instruction Register(IR)? As per my knowledge both store the fetched instruction from the memory and both are Special Purpose Registers.

Comment: Buffer generally corresponds to any kind of data. But Instruction register as the name indicates, will contain only instructions to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in their working during the fetch part of the instruction cycle in a computer processor. The MBR stores any data for input or output, whereas, the IR stores only the instruction that needs to be decoded by the control unit. The cycle is like -- 1.Program Counter --> 2.Memory Address Register --> 3. Instruction Register --> 4. Memory Buffer Register.

Comment: I think it should be  -- 1.Program Counter --> 2.Memory Address Register --> 3.Memory Buffer Register  --> 4. Instruction Register.